# How to make this OpenMP run faster?

Tags: c++, performance, openmp, sparse-matrix

I am new to OpenMP and I have this code of a Sparse Matrix-Vector Multiplication and it runs in between 40 - 50 sec. and has total 4237 MFlops/s. Is there any way to get it faster?
Ss I have edited the post the complete code und Aas an input I have 2 matrices one with 50000 Element and the secound with 400000.

The main problem is when ever I try something different, I get the time to go even worse.

```
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule (static,50)
            for (int i=0; i< (tInput->stNumRows); ++i) {
                 y[i] = 0.0;
                    for (int j=Arow[i]; j<Arow[i+1]; ++j)
                        y[i] += Aval[j]*x[Acol[j]];
            }
```

Comment: There is not a lot more you can do based on the provided code. However, there may be a room for improvement. Please provide a minimal reproducible example so we can check that.

Comment: sorry, I had to edit the question to get the complete code. I also tried #pragma omp parallel for proc_bind (spread) schedule (static,50), but the result didn't get any better

Answer (score 2):

The way thing you can do to improve the performance of the code is to use **vectorization** (thanks to SIMD instructions). Here is the resulting code:

```cpp
for (int i=0; i< (tInput->stNumRows); ++i) {
    double s = 0.0;
    #pragma omp simd reduction(+:s)
    for (int j=Arow[i]; j<Arow[i+1]; ++j)
        s += Aval[j] * x[Acol[j]];
    y[i] = s;
}
```

Note that `y[i]` is not read/written continuously in the loop enabling further compiler optimizations. Please take care to compile the code in `-O3` (or `/O2` for MSVC) for the code to be effectively vectorized. However, this is probably not enough for this code to be vectorized.

Indeed, one issue with this code is the **memory indirection** `x[Acol[j]]` which is very hard to vectorize efficiently. Recent x86-64 processors (the ones with AVX2) and very recent ARM processors (the ones with SVE) have SIMD instructions to do that (although they are not great still due to the memory access pattern). Without these instructions, no compiler will likely vectorize the code. Thus, you should tell to your compiler it can use theses instructions (assuming the target processor is actually recent). For GCC/Clang, one way is to use the non-portable `-march=native`. Another way is to use `-mavx2` combined with `-mfma` on x86-64 processors (although this does not seems to be as good as `-march=native` in this case for very complex reasons).

Another way to improve the code is to mitigate possible **load balancing** issues and unwanted overheads. Indeed, load balancing issues can appear in your code if the expression `Arow[i+1]-Arow[i]+1` is very different for many `i` values. In that case, you can use a `guided` schedule or a `dynamic` one. However, keep in mind that using a non-static schedule may introduces a significant overhead (especially if the loop is very small or the gap between values is huge). Finally, you can move the `omp parallel` directive outside the timing loop body since this can introduce a significant overhead (due to the thread creation regarding the target OpenMP runtime).

Note that the above solutions assume the input matrices are big enough so parallelism is useful. Moreover, if `x` is huge, the code will likely be bounded by the memory hierarchy and there is not much you can do. Sparse matrix computations are often slow because of such issues.

Here is the final code:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // Timing loop
    // [...]

    #pragma omp for schedule(guided)
    for (int i=0; i< (tInput->stNumRows); ++i) {
        double s = 0.0;
        #pragma omp simd reduction(+:s)
        for (int j=Arow[i]; j<Arow[i+1]; ++j)
            s += Aval[j] * x[Acol[j]];
        y[i] = s;
    }

    // [...]
}
```

EDIT: with your input data, the best solution on my machine (with Clang/IOMP) is not to use multiple threads at all since 400000 elements can be computed in roughly 0.3 ms and the overhead of sharing the work between threads is bigger.

Comment: Probably #pragma omp parallel for schedule would yield better results then #pragma omp parallel for schedule (static,50), not sure why chunk = 50

Comment: @dreamcrash Thank you. I forgot to change the `schedule (static,50)` in the first code although this is mentioned later in the post. I modified the code to make it more clear. Based on a simple bench (with GOMP/IOMP) `guided` seems to be the best schedule on random data in this case.

Comment: After changing the code I still get this result.

`Correctness check
Success, correct result: 229.02006 +- 0.000010

Configuration 
Number of Threads: 240
Number of Repetitions:100000
Support for cc-NUMA arch.: 0
Input filename: input-matrix/mat_dim_59319.txt

Time measurements
Total experiment time: 53.8595
Minimum kernel time:  -0.000750065
Maximum kernel time:  1.62068e+09
Arithm. Mean kernel time:  2.45727e+08

Performance results
Total MFlops/s: 3170.28
Minimum MFlops/s: 1.05357e-09
Maximum MFlops/s: -2276.46
Arithm. Mean MFlops/s:  6.94874e-09`

Comment: @A_421 I do not actually understand the output. Why do you have negative MFlops? It seems the performance is not improved. Did you tried *without any threads*? It seems you are on a machine with many cores and Numa effects. As a result, the overhead of sharing the work between the 240 threads should probably be much bigger than actually doing the computation (not to mention creating the 240 threads).

Comment: What kind of set-up are you running? The only thing that comes to my mind where 240 threads actually make sense are the old 5110 Xeon Phi co-processors.